# BFS and DFS in java and making the graph

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I'm trying to make a graph and then Breadth-First Search or Depth-First Search through that graph. How do you implement the graph in Java?

Comment: What form is your graph taking? Cyclic? Acyclic? Tree? What code have you tried to implement for it already, and where are you running into problems? Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This is a very abstract question, as a graph can be represented in dozens different ways (different data structures).

If you're not too familiar with graphs I would recommend you to start with:

- **`Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>` (adjacency list)**
  for sparse graph (when the number of edges is close to the minimal number of edges), where vertices are your keys in the map, and their neighbor vertices are the values.
- **`int[n][n]` (adjacency matrix)**
  for dense graphs (when the number of edges is close to the max number of edges), where n - number of vertices.